# It's in the indents (I think) Python

Tags: python

This is a program that works kinda like a Boggle game. It rolls 16 dice and then you have to pick words out of the rolled letters. Not fancy enough to do the connected dice, just any words longer than 3 from the given letters. It checks the words against a word list and to make sure you don't repeat

This is still basic in scope and very I'm still new to Python 3.3.4.

I think the error is in the indention of the loops in get_guesses(). I have tried moving loops around different loops work at different times.

```
import random
global roll
global rolled
global guesses
global word_list
global start
roll = []
rolled = []
word_list = []
guesses = []

# Setting the dice
die0 = ['r', 'i', 'f', 'o', 'b', 'x']
die1 = ['i', 'f', 'e', 'h', 'e', 'y']
die2 = ['d', 'e', 'n', 'o', 'w', 's']
die3 = ['u', 't', 'o', 'k', 'n', 'd']
die4 = ['h', 'm', 's', 'r', 'a', 'o']
die5 = ['l', 'u', 'p', 'e', 't', 's']
die6 = ['a', 'c', 'i', 't', 'o', 'a']
die7 = ['y', 'l', 'g', 'k', 'u', 'e']
die8 = ['qu', 'b', 'm', 'j', 'o', 'a']
die9 = ['e', 'h', 'i', 's', 'p', 'n']
die10 = ['v', 'e', 't', 'i', 'g', 'n']
die11 = ['b', 'a', 'l', 'i', 'y', 't']
die12 = ['e', 'z', 'a', 'v', 'n', 'd']
die13 = ['r', 'a', 'l', 'e', 's', 'c']
die14 = ['u', 'w', 'i', 'l', 'r', 'g']
die15 = ['p', 'a', 'c', 'e', 'm', 'd']
dice = [die0, die1, die2, die3, die4, die5, die6, die7, die8, die9, die10, die11, die12, die13, die14, die15]

# Importing word list and file handling
def dict():
    game_list = open('TWL06.txt')
    for line in game_list:
        line=line.strip()
        word_list.append(line)
    game_list.close()

# Randomly gets a roll from the dice
def dice_roll():
    global roll
    global rolled
    for die in dice:
        roll.append(random.choice(die))
        rolled = ' '.join(roll)

# breaks the rolled dice into 4 groups of 4 
def game_grid():
    print (rolled[0:8])
    print (rolled[8:16])
    print (rolled[16:24])
    print (rolled[24:32])

    get_guesses()

# Get player input for guessed words
def get_guesses():
    global word_list
    global rolled
    guess = input("Enter a word you found.").upper()
    guess_list = list(guesses)
    if (len(guess)) <= 3:
        print("That word is to short.")
        get_guesses()
    else:
        if guess in word_list:
            for i in guess_list:
                if i not in rolled:
                    print("That word is not in the dice.")
                    get_guesses()
            if guess not in guesses:
                print("That is a good word.")
                guesses.append(guess)
                get_guesses()
            else:
                print("You already guessed that one.")
                get_guesses()
        else:
            print("That is not one of the ", len(word_list), "words I know.")
            get_guesses()

# Main menu
def main():
    print("This game is similar to Boggle")
    print("Your goal is to guess as many words from the rolled dice as you can.")
    print("You can use any letters in the grid to play.")
    print("Your words must be 3 letters or longer.")
    play_quit = input("Press 'p' to play or any other key to quit.").lower()
    if play_quit == "p":
        dict()
        dice_roll()
        game_grid()

    else:
        print("Thanks for playing.")

main()
```

Comment: What's the question? Are you getting an error? If it's syntax-related, then *look at the exception*, it will tell you *exactly* where the problem is.

Comment: It does different things depending on where I move the indents.n right now it takes anything you give it then says everything else is "not in the dice."

Comment: This line is indented too much: `rolled = ' '.join(roll)`. It shouldn't be inside the loop.

Comment: Thanks ooga. I fixed that, but that dose not fix the main problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presumably you intend `guess_list` to be a list of the characters in the user's guest, but in fact you are setting it to a copy of `guesses`, the list of the user's prior words.

Also, you are converting the user's input to upper case, but your randomly-chosen letters are lower case, so you would never find the characters of the user's input in `rolled` anyway.  I don't know what case is used by the contents of `TWL06.txt`.

Many of the names in this program can be improved.

You have a function named `dict`, which is a bad idea because `dict` is a built-in function that creates dictionaries.

You have a variable named `game_list` which is a file, not a list.

You have a variable named `word_list`, which is a list, but `words` would be more concise and just as useful.

You have variables named `die0`, `die1`, `die2`, etc., which are not necessary.  You can just create `dice` using nested list literals.

An iteration variable named `i` implies an integer, but you intend it to be a character.

Also, you use `global` in a lot of places that you don't need it.  You only need it when you're going to assign to a global variable and your assignment statement is in a function.  When you call `append` on a global variable, that doesn't assign to the variable.

```
import random

acceptable_words = []
acceptable_letters = []
user_words = []

dice = [
    ['r', 'i', 'f', 'o', 'b', 'x'],
    ['i', 'f', 'e', 'h', 'e', 'y'],
    ['d', 'e', 'n', 'o', 'w', 's'],
    ['u', 't', 'o', 'k', 'n', 'd'],
    ['h', 'm', 's', 'r', 'a', 'o'],
    ['l', 'u', 'p', 'e', 't', 's'],
    ['a', 'c', 'i', 't', 'o', 'a'],
    ['y', 'l', 'g', 'k', 'u', 'e'],
    ['qu', 'b', 'm', 'j', 'o', 'a'],
    ['e', 'h', 'i', 's', 'p', 'n'],
    ['v', 'e', 't', 'i', 'g', 'n'],
    ['b', 'a', 'l', 'i', 'y', 't'],
    ['e', 'z', 'a', 'v', 'n', 'd'],
    ['r', 'a', 'l', 'e', 's', 'c'],
    ['u', 'w', 'i', 'l', 'r', 'g'],
    ['p', 'a', 'c', 'e', 'm', 'd']]

def load_acceptable_words():
    with open('TWL06.txt') as word_file:
        for line in word_file:
            acceptable_words.append(line.strip().lower())

def roll_dice():
    for die in dice:
        acceptable_letters.append(random.choice(die))

def print_game_grid():
    for i in range(4):
        print_game_row(i)

def print_game_row(i):
    print (' '.join(acceptable_letters[i:i+4]))

def run_game_loop():
    while True:
        run_one_turn()

def run_one_turn():
    candidate = input("Enter a word you found.").strip().lower()
    if (check_is_long_enough(candidate)
        and check_can_be_spelled(candidate)
        and check_is_acceptable_word(candidate)):
        accept_user_word(candidate)

def check_is_long_enough(candidate):
    if len(candidate) >= 3:
        return True
    else:
        print("That word is to short.")
        return False

def check_can_be_spelled(candidate):
    if all(letter in acceptable_letters for letter in candidate):
        return True
    else:
        print("That word is not in the dice.")
        return False

def check_is_acceptable_word(candidate):
    if candidate in acceptable_words:
        return True
    else:
        print("That is not one of the ", len(acceptable_words), "words I know.")
        return False

def accept_user_word(word):
    user_words.append(word)

def main():
    print("This game is similar to Boggle.")
    print("Your goal is to guess as many words from the rolled dice as you can.")
    print("You can use any letters in the grid to play.")
    print("Your words must be 3 letters or longer.")
    play_quit = input("Press 'p' to play or any other key to quit.").strip().lower()
    if play_quit == "p":
        load_acceptable_words()
        roll_dice()
        print_game_grid()
        run_game_loop()
    else:
        print("Thanks for not playing.")

main()
```

Comment: Thanks Rob. A lot of really helpful info here. I finally get a day to sit and try to implement some of the changes you suggested. I'll post back later when I get some of it in, I just didn't want it to go another day without at least saying thanks.

Comment: Ok thanks to all that helped. I took some of the advise and it is working great now. I even got a timer running! I didn't get the indent answers but I call it a victory anyway.